# Access variables from other tasks when using load-grunt-config?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using load-grunt-config to split my gruntfile and I have a requirement to access the variables of one task in another. The tasks are being exported using module.exports. Is it possible to access job variables in one task from another task that runs after it?

```
module.exports= function(grunt) {
    combine: {
        files: {
             'dist/lib.min.css' : ['file1', 'file2']
        }
    }
}

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    for (var file in //grunt.combine.files???
        //do stuff with files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are in need of a shared configuration between two tasks.

load-grunt-config exposes the 'data' object that lets you tweak the grunt configuration.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        // data passed into config. 
        data: {
          files: ['file1', 'file2']
        }

    });
}
```

that you can later use, in your example, as such

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    combine: {
        files: {
             'dist/lib.min.css' : '<%= files %>'
        }
    }
}

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    for (var file in grunt.config('files')) {
        //do stuff with files
    }
}
```